Can't figure out how to allow WinSCP to access a debian machine
I can PuTTY in no problem with a username password. But WinSCP give me the following error:

Couldn't agree a host key algorithm (available: rsa-sha2-512, rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519)

I've searched and searched for ways of resolving this. I've seen people recommend adding HostKeyAlgorithms ssh-rsa,ssh-dss to sshd_config, but that gives me an error on restart (I read that maybe it doesn't support HostKeyAlgorithms?). I'm just not seeing much that seems helpful. Is this possible to do or are these things incompatible until WinSCP decides to update their code?
I'm using Debian 12, OpenSSH_9.2p1, WinSCP 5.7.7.

The error suggests that OpenSSH doesn't support the security algorithm WinSCP is trying to use:

"Couldn't agree a host key algorithm (available: rsa-sha2-512, rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519)"

You need a version of WinSCP that supports one of the algorithms listed:

sa-sha2-512, rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519

The latest version of WinSCP supports most modern algorithms. See:
https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ssh_algorithms
I recommend updating to the latest WinSCP and trying again. Manually set the algorithm to one of the supported ones if you have to.
